# can a function return twice inside a for loop statement

Tags: python

I have the following function that check whether a regex input is legit:

import re

```
def isvalid_regex():
    for _ in range(2):
        try:
            re.compile(input())
            return True
        except re.error:
            return False
```

The problem here is that I don't get a double input as I would expect by `range(2)`. The function returns me `False` or `True` and exits. I guess a function cannot repeat return statements for the number of times of a `for loop in range(x)` exists right ? My goal is to have a double input and a double True or False `return`. For example as output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: I think that `yield` statement is what you want.

Comment: `return` exits from the function. If you want to know the status of every item in your loop, create a list and append `True` or `False` to your list... Then return the list at the end

Comment: I would suggest that you show the part of your code where you are calling isvalid_regex. That would make it easier to give a suggestion about how to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return` statement ends the function.
You have two options:

#### 1. generator

You can learn about generator in: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?#generators

```py
def isvalid_regex():
    for _ in range(2):
        try:
            re.compile(input())
            yield True
        except re.error:
            yield False


for x in isvalid_regex():
    print(x)
```

input and output:

```
t
True
\\\
False
```

#### 2. Build a list and return once

```py
def isvalid_regex():
    results = []
    for _ in range(2):
        try:
            re.compile(input())
            results.append(True)
        except re.error:
            results.append(False)
    return results


for x in isvalid_regex():
    print(x)
```

input and output:

```
t
\\\
True
False
```

#### Note:

You might noticed that **the order of execution is different**. You can choose what fits your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to do.

Functions **do** return only once, but they can return sequences, so you could use that "trick" for returning multiple values.

For example:

```
a = [1, 2]


def squarer(items):
    return [item ** 2 for item in items]


print(squarer(a))
# [1, 4]
```

---

If you want to exit from a function multiple times but then come back to its internal state (for convenience) then you should use a generator.
To do so, you replace the `return` statement with a `yield` one.
With this method, once a `yield` statement is reached, you get a value.
Subsequent values from the generator can be obtained with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#next) or by using the generator in a `for` loop.

For example:

```
def squarer(item):
    for x in range(item):
        yield x ** 2


itr = squarer(4)
# <generator object squarer at 0x7f145c421eb8>
print(itr)
for x in itr:
    print(x)
# 0
# 1
# 4
# 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def isvalid_regex(*expressions): #use *args for allowing any number of arguments instead of hardcoding them
    for expression in expressions: #also dont ask for arguments in a function with input, use arguments and then input in the function's call
        try:
            re.compile(expression)
            yield True #yield creates a generator, a generator is a sequence that asks for a function's next yield in each iteration
        except re.error:
            yield False

#and on your code
for res in isvalid_regex(input(), input()): assert res #you might want to use assertion if youre trying to check validity
```